# В каком заголовочном файле в C++ 11 находится clamp?

Tags: c++

Вопрос в заголовке, без пояснений.

Comment: Ответ - ни в каком.

Answer (score 4):

Есть только в `C++17` 
в заголовочном файле `<algorithm>`. В принципе если вам принципиально нужен `C++11` напишите свою реализацию.

Comment: Судя по этому http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp только начиная с C++17